# SQL Server 2008 R2: Alter view by removing specific table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following 3 tables and created view for all three tables.

**Table**: `s1`

```
CREATE TABLE s1
(
 Cola INT,
 Colb VARCHAR(10)
);
```

**Table**: `s2`

```
CREATE TABLE s2
(
 Cola INT,
 Colb VARCHAR(10)
);
```

**Table**: `s3`

```
CREATE TABLE s3
(
 Cola INT,
 Colb VARCHAR(10)
);
```

**Insertion**:

```
INSERT INTO s1 VALUES(1,'a');
INSERT INTO s1 VALUES(1,'b');

INSERT INTO s2 VALUES(3,'c');
INSERT INTO s2 VALUES(4,'d');

INSERT INTO s3 VALUES(1,'a');
INSERT INTO s3 VALUES(1,'b');
```

**Creating View**: `sx`

```
CREATE VIEW sx as
SELECT * FROM s1
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM s2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM s3;
```

Now I have this:

```
SELECT * FROM Sx;
```

**Result**:

```
-------------
cola    colb
-------------
1       a
1       b
3       c
4       d
1       a
1       b
```

**Note**: I want to `ALTER VIEW` in which I want to remove those tables in which `cola` contains value `1`. And according to me the table `s1` and `s3` has those values.

**Note 1**: If all tables contains value `1` then `VIEW` has to be `drop`.

**Question**: How to alter view by checking specific condition as given above?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Instead Of Trigger:

```
Create Trigger SX_Del On Sx Instead of delete
As 
Begin
    Delete s From s1 s Inner Join deleted d on d.Cola = s.Cola
    Delete From s2 Where cola in (Select Cola From deleted )
    Delete From s3 Where cola in (Select Cola From deleted )
End
```

Just like each different Select in your view, you must define what has to be deleted for each table.